# First run of script is slower

Tags: powershell

I am doing some performance profiling and noticed something very odd. I wanted to compare two ways of building a list of XML files. One uses `Get-ChildItem` twice, with the first one filtering for a single file and the second filtering based on file name, and the second approach uses Get-Item for the single file and `Get-ChildItem` again for the multiple files. I wrapped both in `Measure-Command`.

When I run it, the first run shows a much longer time for the very first `Measure-Command`, but it doesn't matter which approach is first. And it's only the first one over a fair amount of time. So, if we call the two approaches GIGC (`Get-Item` & `Get-ChildItem`) and GCGC (`Get-ChildItem` & `Get-ChildItem`), if I have the order GIGC then GCGC, and I run it I will see 2.5 seconds for GIGC and 1.5 seconds for GCGC. If I immediately rerun it they will both be around 1.5 seconds. It will stay around 1.5 seconds as I rerun over and over. let the console sit for a few minutes and GIGC will again be around 2.5 seconds. BUT, if I reverse it, GCGC first and GIGC second, the numbers remain the same. That first `Measure-Command`, this time of GCGC, will be 2.5 seconds, and all the rest will be 1.5. Let the console sit for long enough and the first one will go back up.

```
$firmAssets = '\\Mac\Support\Px Tools\Dev 4.0'

Measure-Command {
    [Collections.ArrayList]$sourceDefinitions = @(Get-Item "$firmAssets\Definitions.xml") + @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions_*.xml -Recurse)
}
Measure-Command {
    [Collections.ArrayList]$sourceDefinitions = @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions.xml) + @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions_*.xml -Recurse)
}
```

At first I thought the issue might be with `Measure-Command`, so I changed the code to use Get-Date as the timer. Same results.

```
$startTime = Get-Date
[Collections.ArrayList]$sourceDefinitions = @(Get-Item "$firmAssets\Definitions.xml") + @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions_*.xml -Recurse)
Write-Host "$(New-Timespan –Start:$startTime –End:(Get-Date))"

$startTime = Get-Date
[Collections.ArrayList]$sourceDefinitions = @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions.xml) + @(Get-ChildItem $firmAssets -Filter:Definitions_*.xml -Recurse)
Write-Host "$(New-Timespan –Start:$startTime –End:(Get-Date))"
```

So, last test, I thought it might be something related to the console, so I converted to a script. Weirdly, same result! First run is always substantially slower. My (uneducated) guess is that there is some memory initialization thing happening, that happens on the first run and then stays initialized over multiple uses of PowerShell, be it scripts or console. Basically some sort of PowerShell overhead, which feels like something we can't work around. But hopefully someone has a better answer than my "That's just how PowerShell works, get over it"

Comment: That's just how computers (this behavior is not specific to PowerShell) works, get over it.

Comment: Many applications (including PowerShell) use caching mechanisms to improve performance. First execution is slow, because everything must be computed. subsequent executions are faster, because they can work with pre-computed cached values, until the caches get invalidated over time. Rinse and repeat. Google "cache pre-warming".

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the case, but good to get a verification.